# How to pass an argv[] value from main to an outside function

Tags: c, scope, global-variables, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I am working on a C program that is a modified version of an ls command. I have gotten much of the program done, but I am stuck on a specific part. I am trying to pass last argc argument into a function that is outside of main (in another file to be more exact). I tried implementing solutions like:

```
char ** filePattern;
filePattern = argv; 
int * numArguments;
numArguments = &argc;
```

The above code is in my main. Then I'm doing this in another file:

```
//This Function is Passed to ftw by main.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ftw.h>
int listFunc (const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
{    
    //importing the argv and argc from main using pointers


     //if the call to stat failed, then just return
     if (type == FTW_NS)
     {        
        return 0;
     }  

     //Otherwise, if filename matches the filedescriptor entered by user,
     //return found files, their size and filename (with directory)  
     if(type == FTW_F)
     {          
        if(fnmatch(filePattern[numArguments - 1], name,0 )==0)
        {    
             printf("%ld\t%s\n", status->st_size, name);
        } 
     }
     else
     {
        if(fnmatch(filePattern[numArguments - 1], name,0 )==0)
        { 
            printf("%ld\t%s*\n", status->st_size, name);
        }
     } 

 return 0;
}
```

Pretty much gist of this assignment is to get a wildcard filepattern like *foo.c. search the directory and subdirectoires, and return the result (file size and file name) plus other stuff I havent mentioned. This is the part that I am stuck on and is holding me back from moving forward.

The function listFunc is getting called by following function inside main: `ftw(".", listFunc, 1);`

I could post the actual assignment and all of my code so far on here but that would be considered cheating wouldn't it...so I want to avoid that.

Comment: the filePattern argument is the last argument, thats why I am using numArguments -1 as my index.

Comment: numArguments is a pointer, I think `filePattern[numArguments - 1]` is wrong. Maybe `filePattern[*numArguments - 1]`?

Comment: `argv` is whatever you pass to the binary being executed. If you want ot pass to your `ls` what the user typed, then from within `main` use `fgets` like so:
`fgets(lineBuffer, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stdin);`  and then pass `lineBuffer` to whatever function you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to understand.

Add the required argument to the function, and pass it from `main()` when you call. Don't use global variables!

Like so:

```
int listFunc (const char *pattern, const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
{
  ...
}
```

and then in `main()`:

```
listFunc(argv[argc - 1], rest of parameters ...);
```

It's `argc - 1` since `argv` is 0-based like all C arrays.

I'm not sure I follow what the `listFunc()` is supposed to do, but this is how to pass a value from a function to another.

Comment: ah yes sorry I wasnt more specific / clear. Been working on this for about 12 hours and my brain is barely making comprehensive sentences or logical sense. Anyway. To shed some light on the errors that I am getting while compiling (before making any adjustments):

listFunc.c: In function 'listFunc':
listFunc.c:28:20: error: 'filePattern' undeclared (first use in this function)
listFunc.c:28:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
listFunc.c:28:32: error: 'numArguments' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: the problem is, I am using this function in the following code: `ftw(".", listFunc, 1);`. as you can see, the ftw() call doesnt use any parameters straight up from my listFunc function, so I dont know if I can add any more arguments to the function